# Test old commit in Git Repository

Tags: git, git-revert, gitkraken

I currently have a Project(JavaScript) with a bug in it and I am sure that I fixed it sometime ago, now my Question is how to revert to an old commit and check that Version on my localhost.

But I do not want to loose any changes in my git repo I just want to check how the Project look at commit X, how do I manage that.

I am using gitkraken as a gui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Be sure you have no uncommited changes; commit or stash them if necessary
- Create a new branch at your current HEAD (using the `Branch` button)
- Search the commit you want to take a look at
- Right click the commit, choose `Reset <branchname> to this commit` > `Hard - discard all changes`. This will reset the branch you just created to this commit.
- You travelled back in time. Test and check everything you need to. If you want to go back to the present, just check out your original branch.

EDIT:
There's an even easier way!

- Be sure you have no uncommited changes; commit or stash them if necessary
- Search the commit you want to take a look at
- Right click the commit, choose `Create branch here`. Enter a branch name. This will create a branch at this commit.
- Check out the newly created branch by double-clicking.
- You travelled back in time. Test and check everything you need to. If you want to go back to the present, just check out your original branch.

Comment: A good `gitkraken` answer! I see gitkraken doesn't just `checkout` to a commit.

Comment: This worked thanks alot, is this a good "practice" for issues like this?

Comment: Yes. It's very cheap to create branches in git, so it's completely legit to create some to move around in your repository's history. It's generally advisable to create backup branches before you perform potentially destructive operations like rebases or hard resets. Having that said, it's by no means *necessary* to create branches for this purpose; when you use git via command line, you can use `git checkout <commit-id>` to checkout commits directly; although this will lead to a detached HEAD state. In gitkraken, however, you will always need to work with branches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure when the bug was introduced/fiex you can use the *bisect* approach of git: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect

```
git bisect start
git bisect bad COMMIT_KNOWN_TO_FAIL
git bisect good COMMIT_KNOWN_TO_PASS
```

Then git will select a commit in the middle. You can do your check and depending on the result of your test you call:

```
 git bisect good
```

if the test passes and

```
 git bisect bad
```

if the test fails.

Then git selects another commit towards the former *good* if the test failed and towards the **bad* if the test passed.

Since you're looking for when the problem **dis**appeard you might have to switch the meaning of "good" and "bad" when continuing...

when you identified the malicios commit call

```
git bisect reset
```